# Rearranging uniq rows in text file

Tags: perl, awk, uniq

I have a txt file which looks like this below
Input file: test.txt

```
AC1   CAFA
AC2   CGSD
AC3   FGGB
AC1   GHSH
AC2   GHSR
AC1   FGR
```

my expected output: sum (number of rows belong to at the column 3)

```
AC1   CAFA,GHSH,FGR  3
AC2   CGSD,GHSR  2
AC3   FGGB  1
```

I tried with awk first:

```
 awk '{line="";for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) line = line $i ","; table[$1]=table[$1] line;}
      END {for (key in table) print key "\t" table[key];}' test.txt | sort
```

Comment: What have you tried? We're not here to do your work for you, but we'll help you fix the problems in your script. You simply need to make two associative arrays keyed off the first column: one contains the count, the other contains the concatenated items in column 2.

Comment: I tried with awk first. awk '{line="";for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) line = line $i ","; table[$1]=table[$1] line;} END {for (key in table) print key "\t" table[key];}' test.txt | sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little Perl solution that you may like. It expects the input file as a parameter on the command line.

All it does is split each line of the file on whitespace and fill the hash `%data` where the keys `AC1`, `AC2` etc. are related to references to arrays of all the corresponding values for that key. Once the hash has been populated it is simple to dump the data in the form required.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<>) {
  my ($key, $val) = split;
  push @{ $data{$key} }, $val;
}

for my $key (sort keys %data) {
  my $list = $data{$key};
  local $" = ',';
  printf "%s   %s  %d\n", $key, "@$list", 0+@$list;
}
```

**output**

```
AC1   CAFA,GHSH,FGR  3
AC2   CGSD,GHSR  2
AC3   FGGB  1
```

Comment: Don't ask me why I wrote `0+@$list` here instead of the more proper `scalar @$list`. I guess it just seemed to pair better with using `$"` instead of `join`

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the counter in your script:

```
awk '{count[$1]++;line="";for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) line = (line == "") ? $i : line "," $i; table[$1] = ($1 in table) ? line : table[$1] "," line;}
     END {for (key in table) print key "\t" table[key] "\t" count[key];}' test.txt | sort
```

Comment: Still I'm getting an extra comma at the end of each line in the second column. any ideas how to remove that? this is how the output looks now: 
AC1     20,60,20,       3
AC2     30,50,  2
AC3     40,     1

Comment: I've added conditional expressions so it only adds comma if there's already something in the variable.

Comment: in a cheating way, i removed the extra comma using sed from column 2 and then pasted it back.

Comment: @palc you never need sed if you're using awk. Any time you find yourself doing that, stop and think - there's always a better solution in awk itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS='  ' '{ ++counter[$1] } $1 in a { a[$1] = a[$1] "," $2; next } { a[$1] = $2; keys[i++] = $1 } END { for (i = 0; i in keys; ++i) { key = keys[i]; print key, a[key], counter[key] } }' file
```

Output:

```
AC1  CAFA,GHSH,FGR  3
AC2  CGSD,GHSR  2
AC3  FGGB  1
```

Script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    OFS = "  "
}
{
    if ($1 in a) {
        a[$1] = a[$1] "," $2
    } else {
        a[$1] = $2
        keys[i++] = $1
    }
    ++counter[$1]
}
END {
    for (i = 0; i in keys; ++i) {
        key = keys[i]
        print key, a[key], counter[key]
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting a down vote on an answer where OP comments that it works for him is ironic isn't it? `:P`

Comment: People make their own answering rules in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ vals[$1] = (cnt[$1]++ ? vals[$1] "," : "") $2 }
END { for (key in vals) print key, vals[key], cnt[key] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
AC2 CGSD,GHSR 2
AC3 FGGB 1
AC1 CAFA,GHSH,FGR 3
```

With GNU awk if you want the output sorted by the key values:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" }
{ vals[$1] = (cnt[$1]++ ? vals[$1] "," : "") $2 }
END { for (key in vals) print key, vals[key], cnt[key] }

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
AC1 CAFA,GHSH,FGR 3
AC2 CGSD,GHSR 2
AC3 FGGB 1
```

or just pipe to `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `perl` variant:

```
perl -lane '
    push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[1] 
}{ 
    print join " ", $_, join (",", @{$h{$_}}), scalar @{$h{$_}} for sort keys %h' file
AC1 CAFA,GHSH,FGR 3
AC2 CGSD,GHSR 2
AC3 FGGB 1
```

- We split the line on space into an array using `-a` option. The array that gets populated is `@F`.
- We use column1 as key and create a hash of arrays by pushing column2 as list of values.
- In the `END` block we print the key, list of values for that key and the count.
- `-n` option creates a `while` loop to read entire file one line at a time.
- `-l` option chomps the new line and places it back during print.
- `-e` option tells the `perl` to execute the code.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have a `perl` tag:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -an

$h{$F[0]} = [] unless exists $h{$F[0]};
push @{h{$F[0]}},$F[1];

END {
    foreach $key (sort keys %h) {
        $out=$key."\t"; $c=0;
        foreach ( @{$h{$key}} ) {
            $out.=$_.",";
            $c++
        }
        $out=~s/,$//;
        print "$out $c\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
perl test.pl file
AC1 CAFA,GHSH,FGR 3
AC2 CGSD,GHSR 2
AC3 FGGB 1
```

Explanation:

**1.** `#! /usr/bin/perl -an` The `-a` auto-splits the input using default
    field separator, it creates the array `@F`

**2.** Then we create a hash using field1 as key and as value being array reference where we will store field2 for a given key.

The hash will look like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'AC3' => [
                     'FGGB'
                   ],
          'AC2' => [
                     'CGSD',
                     'GHSR'
                   ],
          'AC1' => [
                     'CAFA',
                     'GHSH',
                     'FGR'
                   ]
        };
```

**3**. Then we just print accordingly.

Comment: Very unorthodox way of joining the list of values. The counter is off too.

Comment: @jaypal yeah, I need to make use of `join` more often `:)`

Comment: @Tiago: i) There's no need for the first statement at all. Perl will *autovivify* the appropriate hash value when you try to `push` to a non-existent element. ii) You should have explained that you get a `push on reference is experimental` warning, which could have been avoided if you had used the correct `push @{ $h{$F[0]} }, $F[1]`

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what Perl will do for you. You are using qualifiers `-a` and `-n` in the shebang when they are really meant for use with one-line commands. As a result you have put the entirety of your program inside a `while` loop and have been forced to use an `END` block as a hack to print the final data structure just once. Filling the hash is the easy part (see my solution) and you don't need the special behaviour that `-an` gives you. And removing them means you no longer need the `END` block, making everything much neater. I hope this helps

Comment: @Borodin thanks for spotting the unnecessary 1st statement, WRT `-a` I am fully aware of what it does,if I don't use it I would have to open a file and loop through it. I know it's used mostly for one-liners but I wouldn't say that was `meant` to be used for one-liners only.

Comment: @Tiago: No. `-a` is *autosplit*, and without `-F` it's the same as a bare `split`. The `-n` option is what puts a `while` loop around your entire program. And there's no need for any `open` calls if you pass a file on the command line - just use an empty `<>` to read it. A `while (<>) { .. }` is far better than a hacky `END` block. You have written a program that would leave most Perl experts unsure of exactly what it did

Comment: @Borodin I am not a perl expert but I don't think anyone who calls him/herself an expert would have trouble to identify use of switches in the shebang perhaps you don't like because you work from windows box? Anyway  thanks for your time.